# Probability of $Y > X$ between random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, summation, random-variables

## Set up

r.v. $X, Y \sim i.i.d. F$, and $X, Y$ are Discrete random variables.

## Question

$$
P(Y > X) \overset{?}{=} \sum_x \mathbb{P}(Y > x) \mathbb{P}(X = x)
$$

On what basis can this formula be transformed?

Comment: By conditional probability, we have
$$
P(Y > X) = \sum_x P(Y > X | X = x) P(X = x) = \sum_x P(Y > x) P(X = x) = \sum_x P(X > x) P(X = x) = \sum_x \sum_{j > x} P(X = j) P(X = x)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a straightforward application of the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). $X$ and $Y$ don't even have to be i.i.d. and only $X$ needs to be discrete.
(If $X$ is absolutely continuous, you get an integral in place of the sum with the corresponding probability density in place of $P(X=x)$).